# Elasticsearch - refresh config

Tags: elasticsearch, devops

I'm using [elastic cloud](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-custom-bundles.html) and I need to configure synonyms. I've done that successfully by uploading a zip file containing a `elasticsearch/dictionaries/synonyms.txt` file and creating an index that uses them by doing:

```
PUT /synonym_test
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "lowercase",
            "filter": ["porter_stem", "my_synonyms"]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "my_synonyms": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "elasticsearch/dictionaries/synonyms.txt",
            "updateable": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET /synonym_test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer",
  "text": "notebook"
}
```

This works correctly. Now I want to update my `synonyms.txt` file with new entries, which I can do by using the `Extensions API`. Once I've uploaded the new file correctly, I need all the nodes to pick up the new configuration and this is where I'm getting in trouble.

How do I restart the nodes so that they pick up the new config files?

I've tried using the API `/deployments/:deployment_id/elasticsearch/:ref_id/_restart`, which does restart the deployment, but the new synonyms file is not picked up.

I'm looking for a way to programmatically update the deployment, i.e without going to the UI and rebuilding manually

Comment: Have you gone through [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-custom-bundles.html#ec-update-bundles-and-plugins) already?

Comment: yep, I've gone through all the docs and there's nothing mentioning how to automate this step, only how to manually update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating your extension with the new synonyms file, you need to Edit your deployment, click on "Settings and Plugins" to make sure your extension is still checked (it should) and then simply Save your deployment again.

A popup will tell you that no significant changes have been detected, but you can ignore that (i.e. ES Cloud most probably doesn't inspect the content of files) and simply Save your deployment and it will restart again with the new synonyms file.

When updating your extensions, you could also change the name of your extension (e.g. with a version number), then Edit your deployment, click "Setting and Plugins" and swap the old for the new extension. That way ES Cloud will tell you that it detected a change and will restart the nodes upon saving the deployment.

Comment: thanks for your response. However, I'm looking for a way to programmatically do this (ie, via an API). The idea is to be able to update synonyms and trigger a reload dynamically, so that I don't have to go and manually restart the deployment each time.

Comment: In that case, you need to go through the [Deployment Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/Deployment_-_CRUD.html#update-deployment), that's what the UI console does when manually clicking the Save button. You can GET the deployment resource first, modify the user bundle information and PUT it afterwards. That should do the trick.

Comment: Got an answer back from Elastic team saying the solution is not yet supported using only the API, and using the UI is inconvinient at this point. I'll accept your answer even though it's technically not the solution, however it may help someone else looking for this

Comment: Awesome, thanks for providing feedback on this, I'm sure this will help other people. Don't hesitate to chime in once Elastic releases new features that will help with this